# Is it possible to make a YAML use ISO 8601 date format?

Tags: linux, yaml

I am using a tool called [`organize`](https://github.com/tfeldmann/organize) in order to sort folders with a lot of stuff in them and was wondering if it was possible to tell it to create, sort, or rename using *ISO 8601* date format.

The config file goes like this:

```
rules:
    - folders: *private
      subfolders: true
      filters:
          - extension: pdf
          - created
      actions:
          - echo: "Found PDF!"
          - move: /run/media/[REDACTED]/Documents/unsorted_pdfs/{created.year}{created.month}{created.day}/
```

The folders it creates, is named like this: `201781`; I, however, want it named like this: `20170801`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, this is not related to `YAML` but to `organize` itself. Under the ['Advanced Usage' section](https://github.com/tfeldmann/organize#advanced-usage) it says: "Note the format syntax for {created.month} to make sure the month is prepended with a zero.". This means that if you want to prepend a zero to the date, you would have to make the config like this:

```
rules:
    - folders: *private
      subfolders: true
      filters:
          - extension: pdf
          - created
      actions:
          - echo: "Found PDF!"
          - move: /run/media/[REDACTED]/Documents/unsorted_pdfs/{created.year}{created.month:02}{created.day:02}/
```